# Objects and dot notation

Tags: javascript

So I feel like this is probably pretty simple but I can't wrap my head around it. I am reading through an intro to JavaScript book and it provides the following example:

```
function printAmount(amt) {
    console.log(amt.toFixed(2));
}

function formatAmount(){
    return "$" + amount.toFixed(2);
}

var amount = 99.99
```

I don't really understand what `.toFixed` is. The book doesn't define it as part of the example. I know its dot notation but the function doesn't list it as a property anywhere inside of it other than in the console.log in the first function and as part of the return statement in the second one. Is it just another object created within the scope of the function?

I have added a screenshot of the page where it's listed for reference [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9UoJ.png)

Comment: Its a function... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: Did you google for "javascript toFixed"?  Please research before posting, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set `amount` to `99.99`, it has the type of `Number`.

`Number`s have all sorts of convenience methods.  `toFixed()` is an instance function available on `Number`s.

There are others listed on the documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Strictly speaking, `toFixed` is a property defined by the Number prototype, and this property's value is a function.  When you call `someNumber.toFixed()`, you execute the `toFixed` function on `someNumber`.

Comment: "*it has the type of Number, which is a type of Object.*" - uh, no. I think you're simplifying to much here (if that was your intention).

Answer (score 1):

toFixed() method converts any type of number into a string while rounding and leaving only two decimals.

```
   // added value 2 (Wiimm)
   var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

the result is n = 7.97 and it would be a String.

Comment: I added "2" to fix a semantical bug. Feel free to remove my comment.